# What is a difference between Lord Hanuman and Lord Panchmukhi Hanuman? Are they same?

Tags: gods, hanuman

While going through some discussions, I found that *Panchmukhi Hanuman* was altogether a different person but not *Lord Hanuman* and took birth a long time before *Ramayan Time*.

But a recent chit-chat with a friend who revealed me about *Panchmukhi Hanuman* being advance form of *Lord Hanuman* and quoted me with a story of *Ramayan Time*.

I want exact history about both, or both being one entity. (Logically everything is one, that supreme being).

Answer (score 6):

Lord Hanuman and Panchmukhi Hanuman both are same.

During the Ramayana war, Ravan's Brother Mahiranvan took Ram & Laxman to patal-lok. Hanuman went to patal-lok to protect Ram, Laxman & bring them back. After reaching patal-lok Lord hanuman found out that to kill Mahiravan one has to extinguish five lamps (life of Mahiravana is in 3 places, lamps are one of them) burning in five different directions at the same time, so he has taken the Panchamukha form. Hayagriva, Narasimha, Garuda and Varaha faces and extinguished the lamps and killed Mahiravana.

[Panchmukhi Hanuman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchamukha).

Comment: I have also heard that panchmukhi hanuman was created by shiva and vishnu as special plan, who didn't took birth but prakated(I don't have english word for this), is that true.

Comment: I got this story http://aajtak.intoday.in/story/panchmukhi-hanuman-story-1-732591.html, what about this.

Comment: I purely dont trust on news links. If you visit www.divyabhaskar.com & read its stories on God then you are going to be mad. Lets wait for other useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

God Hanuman’s pancha-mukhi (5 faced) avatara is praised as that of a monkey, Narasimha (lion), Garuda, Varaha (boar) and Haya (horse) [Ref: Parashara Samhita 2.9, 58.18].

God Hanuman took a panchamukhi (5-faced) form to help Sita defeat Shatanana, the asura [Ref: Parashara Samhita 7.56-57].

I am not aware of any scriptural source for God Hanuman taking a pancha-mukhi form to kill Mahiravana. It is probably from folklore, but I do believe in that story too.